# Looking for a Star Trek: 2009 movie fic with dying Bones and caring Spock and Kirk

Tags: story-identification, star-trek, fan-fiction

I am looking for this fic I read it was a Star Trek The Movie fic: Where Bones tells Spock he is dying and not to tell Kirk, Spock tells him he has a cure for his illness from Spock prime. Spock tells Kirk that McCoy was sick but didn't tell him he was dying. That's all I remember thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The story is [Live](https://fanfiction.net/s/11020046/1/Live) by Nausicaa Smith.

Comment: Could you [edit](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/229367/edit) this to explain how it matches?

Answer (score 1):

Could it be [To Save a Healer](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/10308555/1/Star-Trek-To-Save-a-Healer)?

Comment: Could you [edit] this to explain how it matches?